How do I bundle an executable in my vscode extension and use it
I want to use a bundled executable that comes in with my extension. I can use an executable that exists in usr/bin/my-exe for example but cannot use an executable I bundle with the extension.
For example with this project structure
packcage.json
client/extension.js
bundled/my-exe

In extension.js I do:
    /** @type {import("vscode").WorkspaceConfiguration} */
    const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('my-exe');
    const intreperterPath = config.get('intreperterPath');
    /** @type {import("vscode-languageclient/node").ServerOptions} */
    const serverOptions = {
      run: {
        command: intreperterPath,
      },
    };

Is there a extensionRootPath I am missing? Also how can I verify first the executable does not exist on the path provided and then use the bundled version?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at how to ask.

Tutorials like mine have existed for years, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/how-to-acquire-dependencies-for-visual-studio-code-extensions-9ca828cb168d
